# Is seaborn.histplot incompatible with FacetGrid.map()?

Tags: dictionary, seaborn, histogram, facet-grid

Let's say we have a Dataframe in JupyterNotebook as follows:

```
tips = {'time': ['morning', 'morning', 'lunch', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'dinner'],
       'tip' : [20, 18, 10, 30, 45, 53]}

df_tips = pd.DataFrame(tips)
```

Now, we want to check the amount of tips at different times using `FacetGrid.map()`.
Accordingly:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_tips, col= 'time')
g.map(sns.histplot, 'tip')
plt.savefig('Test_1')
```

leads to no figure [0 axis using sns.histplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb8uE.png).

**However**, when I use `plt.hist` instead of `sns.histplot`, I get the histogram.
[successful histogram drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrtpP.png)

Based on the seaborn's documentation (https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html), `sns.histplot` should work too. Why doesn't the function work in my case?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you get. Are you using the latest Seaborn 0.11.1?  By the way, in Jupyter it might help to place `g = sns.FacetGrid(...)` and `g.map(...)` into the same cell.

Comment: @JohanC Yes I use the latest version of Seaborn. I put the code in the same cell, however, the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the very latest seaborn 0.11.2 (released a few hours ago)?

Comment: @JohanC I upgraded the sns to the 0.11.2 version and the problem is solved. Thanks a lot!